# Rigging: not whole Mixamo character .fbx imported to Blender

Tags: import, .fbx

I downloded one of the ready mixamo characters as the fbx file. I tried to import this file to blender. However as shown in the followong image, only the bones can be seen in blender and the mesh does not exist. I downloded several characters and all of them have the same problem. What can i do to solve this problem?.[image]

Comment: Did you set the right options in the import dialog ('Import FBX' panel on bottom left)?

Comment: Yes. I have seen related toturials and i set the required options in the import panel.

Comment: Did you download "With skin" ?

Comment: I downloaded with skin and without skin models. unfortunately they didnt work. Three days ago i downloaded a default mixamo model and imported it to belender without any problem. However, in the new imported models only bones can be seen. I think that there is a specific setting in blender which leads to this problem.